# Counter-Increment Not Working Dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js, css-counter

Is it possible to dynamically change the counter-increment number each time a new subject line is generated, as seen below?

The counter-increment number is not changing when generating a new subject line dynamically?

[image: Example of Counter-Increment not working]

If a new fiddle could please be provided, it would be very much appreciated, as I am still new to coding.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/InnovativeDave/q1j4928n/7/)

Thank You!

HTML:

```
<button class="button" data-bind="click: addClass">Add a New Class</button>
<button class="button">
Apply
</button>
<hr>

<ul align="center" data-bind="foreach: classes">
    <li>
        <label class="number">Subject:</label><input type="text" data-bind="value: title" placeholder="E.g: English"/>
        <select disabled data-bind="value: credits">
        <option  selected data-bind="value: credits">1</option>
        </select>
        <label>Grade:</label>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: letterGrade" placeholder="E.g: A+"/>
        <br>
        <br>
    </li>
</ul>



<hr />

<br>
<h4>
Your GPA is: <b><span data-bind="text: totalGPA"></span></b>
</h4>
<br>
<h4>
Final Grade: <span data-bind="text: totalGrade"></span>
</h4>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata:400);
* { text-rendering: optimizelegibility;}
body, input, textarea, select, button { font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; }
pre { font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace; }

span {font-size: 18px;}


h1 {font-size: 25px;}



.number {
    counter-reset: subsection;
}

.number:after {
    counter-increment: section;
    content: " " counter(section) ". ";
}
```

JQuery:

```
var gradeMapping = {
        'A+': 15,
        'A': 14,
        'A-': 13,
        'B+': 12,
        'B': 11,
        'B-': 10,
        'C+': 9,
        'C': 8,
        'C-': 7,
        'D+': 6,
        'D': 5,
        'D-': 4,
        'E+': 3,
        'E': 2,
        'E-': 1
    }
function Class(title, credits, letterGrade) {
    var self = this;
    self.title = ko.observable(title);
    self.credits = ko.observable(credits);
    self.letterGrade = ko.observable(letterGrade);
    self.gpa = ko.computed(function() {
        return gradeMapping[self.letterGrade()];
    });
}

function GpaCalcViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.classes = ko.observableArray();
    self.totalGPA = ko.computed(function() {
        var totalWeightedGPA = 0,
            totalCredits = 0;
        $.each(self.classes(), function() {
            totalWeightedGPA += (this.gpa() * this.credits());
            totalCredits += (this.credits() * 1);
        })
        return totalWeightedGPA / totalCredits;
    });
    self.totalGrade = ko.computed(function() {
        var totalWeightedGPA = 0,
            totalCredits = 0;
        var gradeLetter = null;
        $.each(self.classes(), function() {
            totalWeightedGPA += (this.gpa() * this.credits());
            totalCredits += (this.credits() * 1);
        });
        $.each(gradeMapping, function(letter, number) {
                if(number == Math.round(totalWeightedGPA / totalCredits)){
                gradeLetter = letter;
            }
        })
        return gradeLetter;
    });
    self.addClass = function() {
        self.classes.push(new Class());
    }
};
var viewModel = new GpaCalcViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: Please try to trim the code to the *minimal* needed repro. There's *a lot* of things going on in your code seemingly unrelated to the issue, but there's also bits missing I think (e.g. the view code for the number). Check "[mcve]" for guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with Knockout but with [CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters).

You need to reset your `section` counter first but you have to do it on the "container" level:

```
.list {
    counter-reset: section;
}

.number:after {
    counter-increment: section;
    content: " " counter(section) ". ";
}
```

And add the "list" class to your `ul`:

```
<ul align="center" class="list" data-bind="foreach: classes">
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/gqjgko04/

A more Knocout solution would be to use the `$index` to generate your label, something like:

```
<label data-bind="text: 'Subject: ' + ($index() + 1) + '.'"></label>
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/gqjgko04/1/.

Or using the container less syntax to remove the string concatenation:

```
<label>Subject: <!-- ko text: $index() + 1 --><!-- /ko -->. </label>
```